# How does a shock box toy work?

Tags: circuit-analysis, electromagnetism

There is a toy called shock box, where when opened it delivers a shock. It delivers a shock when opened because the circuit is broken, appareantly similarly to a how a car is started. This toy is powered by a 9 volt battery and two grouos of looped copper wires (about 1:15 ratio). You may notice i am not very knowledgable in the field of electromagnetism, so here is a video of how it is built to better explain it:
https://youtu.be/0Z37iZDx63w

My question is, what is the theory behind how this works?

Comment: Theory: \$V = L\dfrac{di}{dt}\$ or Faraday's law of induction. I didn't watch the video BTW.

Comment: The video you have linked is nothing to do with electric shocks.

Comment: The video is of a vibration box, not a shock box.

Answer (score 4):

The device in the video does not literally deliver an electrical shock. It is merely a vibrator (a DC motor with an eccentric mass attached to the shaft) wired in series with a N.C. microswitch contact and a battery.

It’s possible to make a very simple electromechanical circuit to literally shock people, but I don’t think that’s very funny so I won’t bother showing it.

Comment: `I don’t think that’s very funny so I won’t bother showing it.` this.